# How do I make Blender 2.8 use my graphics card?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I had been using Blender 2.79b on my computer for a while and had my NVIDIA GeForce 1650 card doing my renders fine. Then when I upgraded to 2.8, the card was not recognized as a compatable compute device. It didn't even show any options.

Comment: You likely need to update your graphics driver (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx).

Comment: OK, that actually fixed the problem (after i reattached the graphics card to the motherboard, it had come loose). thank you for the help.